# Getting error while creating PFAnonymousUser using Parse iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, pfuser

In iOS application i am using Parse SDK.

I am creating Parse Anonymous user using the code

```
[PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Anonymous login failed.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Anonymous user logged in.");
    }
}];
```

I am able to create Anonymous user previously.
I am getting error like below in console. and not creating PFUser

**+[BFTask taskFromExecutor:withBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3ee868**

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

- Download the latest Facebook SDK and replace old frameworks in your project.
- Copy Bolts.framework in your Frameworks folder (Don't know why but don't import it in your xCode project)

Compile & run and you shouldn't have any problem.